# Insert prefix text into database in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

can I insert prefix text into the database? prefix text like this:

[image]

I think prefix text (+62) entered the database when it was submitted but no ... is there another way to have +62 auto in TextFormField and can it enter the database ??

and this is my code `

```
    TextFormField(                                                                                    
      controller: controllerPhone,                                                                                 
      decoration: InputDecoration(
       labelText: "Phone",
       icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
       prefixText: '+62',                                                                                    
   ),                                                                                    
   validator: validatePhoneNumber,
   onSaved: (String value) {
     phone = value;
  },                                                                                 ),
```

`

Comment: Will it only be the prefix '+62' or can it vary?

Comment: just prefix "+62", but later I insert phone number data like "+62" 82 ****

Comment: `String phone = '+62' + controllerPhone.text;`

Comment: @MuratAslan when I put it, the controllerPhone error. did I put it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make the prefix a variable and concatenate it in your onSaved():

```dart
String _prefix = '+62'; // somewhere in your code

    TextFormField(                                                                                    
      controller: controllerPhone,                                                                                 
      decoration: InputDecoration(
       labelText: "Phone",
       icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
       prefixText: _prefix,                                                                                    
   ),                                                                                    
   validator: validatePhoneNumber,
   onSaved: (String value) {
     phone = '$_prefix $value';
  },
```

Let me know how this works out for you.

Comment: it doesn't work, only the value behind "+62" is entered.

Comment: if you add `print('phone: $phone');` after declaring the variable, what is printed then? Can you please add your method where you are submitting the number (and possibly other data as well)?

Comment: strangely when I was only onSaved _prefix who came in why the value was

Comment: That's troublesome. Please try adding `print('value: $value');` and report the result.

Comment: was added under 'phone = value' ??

Comment: What is the outcome? If your value contains anything, then it might be because you do not save your form before submitting it leaving the values null. [Link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField/onSaved.html). Particular: *An optional method to call with the final value when the form is saved via FormState.save.*